# How to switch from Budgie to Gnome or other ubuntu desktop environments

Tags: gnome, budgie

I installed Budgie 18.04 recently. However, I am trying to install other Ubuntu desktop environments as well. I installed gnome and xfce4 using apt. However I am unable to find any options to switch between these DEs. I tried all I could to look for options to switch from Budgie to Gnome but couldnt find any. Please help me out here. I am kinda new to Ubuntu world.

Thanks

Comment: There should be a menu widget at the bottom (or somewhere) of your graphical login screen where you can select another DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select the desktop environment you want to run from the log in screen. Before entering your name and password on the login screen, click the cog icon. This will reveal a little menu with your available desktop environments. Choose the one you want to load, then enter your login and password to log in to your selected desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very helpful. One more request please, how can I change my default DE from Budgie to something else?

Comment: The last desktop you logged into remains the default for subsequent log ins.